# How to use include-what-you-use in my cpp project (win)?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, llvm, iwyu

Noob question here, but I can manage to install include-what-you-use...
Which files do I need to download and which is the correct folder I need to point CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to? Or is there another way to use iwyu without building it myself?
I want to be able to use iwyu in my cmake project.
I need to build on windows.

I switched to the clang_15 branch, downloaded and unzipped clang+llvm-15.0.0-amd64-pc-solaris2.11.tar.xz from https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-15.0.0 and ran cmake, but it throws this error multiple times:

```
CMake Error at C:/Users/morit/Documents/dev/iwyu/clang+llvm-15.0.0-amd64-pc-solaris2.11/clang+llvm-15.0.0-amd64-pc-solaris2.11/lib/cmake/llvm/AddLLVM.cmake:932 (add_executable):
  Target "include-what-you-use" links to target "ZLIB::ZLIB" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:101 (add_llvm_executable)
```

downloading LLVM-15.0.0-win64.exe also does not work...

I ran cmake with `cmake -S . -B build "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Program Files\LLVM"` (from source tree, with build as build folder)
I do not want to build clang myself since this would take ages.

Comment: I just built **clang** a few days ago.  Took less time to compile **clang** than my project takes to compile.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are most likely experiencing is that you are using `binaries` build with a specific **compiler A**. Yet you are building a project with a different **compiler B** and trying to include the `binaries` from **compiler A**.

This won't work, because the `binaries` are different! You need to use the same compiler for both your libraries and your current project. This is most likely the reason why your `CMake` can't find an existing and installed library.

EDIT: If you are using the same compiler. Then the issue is as the error states due to a missing dependency `ZLIB`.

EDIT2: To answer your question regarding `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` you should forget about it and instead update your `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` which is a list variable. This variable should contain the `path` to the `findZLIB.cmake` files (respectively `findXYZ.cmake` files of the given dependency). The author of the library should include the list of dependencies he uses and if not you can check out the `CMakeLists.txt` file for the information you need.